# OpenGLView inside a UIView

Tags: ios, uitableview, opengl-es

I have a `UITableView` when a row is selected another `ViewConroller` is pushed and that `ViewContoller` should have a `GLView`. I am not sure about adding an `OpenGLView` as a `subview` to `UIView`.

Do let me know how we can add an `OpenGLView` inside a `UIView`.

Comment: Well try it out yourself??  I don't it'll take more than 1 minute to put a OpenGLView on an UIView..?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an OpenGLView, merely a standard UIView that you've subclassed to have its backing layer be a CAEAGLLayer. You can call the view whatever you want.

Therefore, they behave just like any other UIView subclass and can be added as a subview of another UIView like usual. Nothing special is needed here.